# Delphi - Centrar un label en un form a determinada altura

Tags: delphi, lazarus

Muy buenas, tengo el siguiente problema:

Estoy intentando crear un formulario sencillo en tiempo de ejecución donde se muestran unas `TLabel`, y necesito que estén centradas y a una altura determinada cada una. He podido centrarlas correctamente utilizando `TLabel.Align := alClient` y `TLabel.Alignment := taCenter`, pero no logro asignarle la altura que necesito, porque `TLabel.Layout` sólo me deja especificar arriba, centro o abajo.

¿Cómo puedo asignarle a la `TLabel` un valor de altura como por ejemplo `ClientHeight div 3`?

Tengo este código para crear una label:

```
with TLabel.Create(Self) do
begin
  Align := alClient;
  Alignment := taCenter;
  Top := (F.ClientHeight div 3) * 2;
  caption:= 'Texto de la etiqueta';
  Font.Size:= 18;
  Font.Color := RGB(128, 0, 0);
  Parent:= F;
end;
```

Parece que al aplicar `Align` y `Alignment` ignora lo que le especifico en `Top`, entonces no sé cómo darle el valor deseado.

**EDIT**:

Estoy usando `Lazarus v1.6RC1` en `Windows 10`. La aplicación también es para `Windows 10`.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Estaría bien, como dato añadido, que comentaras la versión de Delphi con la que trabajas y la plataforma destino (windows, Android/iOS).

Comment: Hola, gracias, acabo de editar la pregunta con esa información.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema, es que si estás utilizando como alineación para el componente `TLabel.Align := alClient`, esto hará que el componente se ajuste de forma automática (para su ancho y su alto) para ocupar todo el espacio disponible del componente que lo contiene.

Al ser así, las propiedades ancho y alto ya no puedes asignarlas de forma manual como comentas (`label1.width := ClientHeight div 3`), porque serán ignoradas.

Tendrás que cambiar la propiedad de alineación (`TLabel.Align`) y entonces podrás asignar manualmente el ancho y el alto.

**AÑADO:** En las últimas versiones de delphi, hay un componente llamado [TGriPanelLayout](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/FMX.Layouts.TGridPanelLayout) que facilita posicionar varios componentes en un form. Tal vez en lazarus exista alguno parecido.

Comment: Entonces, hay alguna forma eficaz de centrar horizontalmente la etiqueta sin utilizar Align?

Comment: Para centrarla manualmente, se puede utilizar el evento OnResize del Formulario o del componente contenedor. Utilizando algo similar a lo que has comentado. `Label1.Top := (ClientHeight DIV 2)`.

Comment: La solución ha sido el OnResize, gracias por tu ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

A veces es interesante no usar Align ni aligment ... sin osar las propiedades anchor de cada componente, por si se redimensiona el form donde se encuentren ...

No se si te puede valer esto ....

http://wiki.freepascal.org/Anchor_Sides

Saludos.